# Using an enum index to limit records

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.5, performance, query-performance

A common issue, just not sure on the keywords.

I have a table of assessments (14k+ records).

Each assessment can be in many different states ('draft', 'proofing', 'amends', etc... and 'done').

Most records (13k) are 'done'... so doing a:

```
WHERE state != 'done'
```

It should ignore most records, however MySQL ignores the index (presumably due to the low cardinality).

I could `USE/FORCE INDEX`, which kind of helps, but was wondering if this is the best approach.

One option is to add a `datetime` for when it is done, but not really used at the moment... but would have high cardinality (with `NULL` for those 1k records).

Comment: Please mention your MySQL version and the results you get when you try this:  instead of what I assume you are doing, `WHERE state != 'done'` try the opposite and comment on what you see: `WHERE STATE IN ('draft','proofing','amends')` listing every other possible state except 'done'.  It's a little counter-intuitive but at least in 5.6 the optimizer seems to choose the index with `WHERE ... IN ()` but not with `WHERE ... !=` on an ENUM.  Also, explain what you mean by use/force index "kind of helps".

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot, I've updated and your suggestion to use `WHERE ... IN ()` seems to help (will continue to test).

Comment: Can you add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE name;` output? What is the engine of the table?

Comment: It's MyISAM at the moment (for a `FULLTEXT` index)... and the table structure is quite big (storing lots of text/tinytext values)... so using the INDEX is quite important... but most important is working out how to solve this problem in general, as I've had it come up a couple of times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While similar queries with `=` or `<` or `<=` will consider (and depending on cardinality estimates will use) an index on `(state)`, a query with a condition of this type will **not** use an index.:

```
WHERE state <> 'done'
```

Things you can do instead:

- write the condition as:

  ```
  WHERE (state < 'done' OR state > 'done')
  ```
- use `UNION`:

  ```
  SELECT a.*
  FROM assessments AS a
  WHERE state < 'done'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT a.*
  FROM assessments AS a
  WHERE state > 'done' ;
  ```
- write the condition with `IN` / `OR`:

  ```
  WHERE state IN  ('draft', 'proofing', 'amends', ...)    -- everything except 'done'

  WHERE (state = 'draft' OR state = 'proofing' OR state = 'amends' OR ...)
  ```

Comment: I was doing `state != "done"`, which seems to be the same as `<>`... doing the query with an OR or UNION does not seem to have an effect... but the `WHERE state IN ()` does defiantly help... now as I have a fairly long list of states that I don't want to hard code (more could be added), would adding a `SHOW COLUMNS` really be a good idea (that would defiantly add time).

Comment: Add `SHOW COLUMNS` where? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: As in use `SHOW COLUMNS` to return a list of the possible enum values, then use that to build the query (dropping the "done" state)... i.e. so the multiple queries that use this don't need to hard code the possible values (which can change, and will always need to just ignore the "done" state)... I can't imagine that would be a good idea though.